# Templates render fast locally but slow on live server

Tags: performance, speed

On my server my page loads in about 800-2.200ms. Locally it's loading in about 100ms.  The database loads super fast on server and locally. When I use profiling locally my content matrix template takes around 5ms to render but on the server it takes about 300ms and the footer also takes 300ms. I improved my speed locally by using eager loading but it doesn't seem to help on my sever.

I've tested creating a phpinfo file and seeing how fast it loads on the server and it's loading super fast so it's not any server settings.

Do you have any ideas? I do use imager in Craft for every image but why would it be slower on the server and not locally as well?

Comment: What sort of hosting do you have? Is devMode turned on the server too?

Comment: @RitterKnight I use basic Strato hosting. All the PHP ini settings are fine based on the craft report and devmode is off.

Comment: Is it a shared hosting? I could imagine that this is the bottleneck. Using a VPS provisioned by Forge or something similar should result even in better performance than locally depending on your setup.

Comment: @Johannes yes it's shared hosting. I guess too bad then bc the client will definetly not switch. Thanks!